# Does the value of the Ricci scalar determine the strength of the gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, curvature

If I was solving an equation that contains the Ricci Scalar, and I want to solve the equation in the strong and weak gravity regimes, is right to assume that $R>>1$ for first case and $R<<1$ in the second case, then simplify the equation and solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The magnitude of the Ricci scalar places no restrictions on the Weyl tensor. After all, in the Schwarzschild metric the Ricci scalar is zero everywhere (except at the singularity where it's undefined). You may be able to link the Ricci scalar to the curvature in your specific case, but in general your assumption is not a safe one.

Comment: Why is the that when people consider modifying gravity, they consider something like $R+1/R$ for late uni, so they are verse, assuming that $R->0$ as the universe becomes flat in the late universe.

Comment: @435145: A flat universe certainly has $R = 0$, but $R = 0$ doesn't necessarily mean the universe is flat.

Answer (score 0):

There are different measures of the strength of the gravitational field. One is the curvature, which is a nice local geometric invariant. However, the curvature only becomes "large" in very extreme situations, like near the singularity of a black hole. The curvature is actually not large near the event horizon (ie, you can't do local experiments to tell you are crossing an event horizon, you don't feel anything weird as you pass through), even though we would probably want to say the gravitational field is strong there. Another measure is "how far from flat is the metric", meaning if you write $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$, is $h$ big or small? This is a little more vague and coordinate dependent, but it can be a useful perspective, for example in Schwarzchild coordinates $h$ becomes big near the horizon. If you like, it's saying that the flat coordinates natural to an observer at infinity no longer look natural to an observer near the event horizon.

From an effective field theory perspective, we can imagine writing the most general gravitational action as
\begin{equation}
S=\int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} \left( \Lambda+M_{pl}^2 R + c_1 R^2 + c_2 R_{\mu\nu}^2+\cdots\right)
\end{equation}

where $c_{1,2}$ are dimensionless constants. When the curvature is small $R\ll M_{pl}^2$, it becomes a good approximation to only focus on the first two terms. In other words, General Relativity *is* the low curvature limit of a full theory of gravity.

On the other hand, what we usually mean by weak gravity is that we can linearize Einstein's equations. In other words, writing
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu} + \frac{h_{\mu\nu}}{M_pl}
\end{equation}
then (assuming $\Lambda=0$) we can write the Einstein hilbert action schematically as
\begin{equation}
S\sim M_{pl}^2 \int d^4 x \sum_n \partial^2 \left(\frac{h}{M_{pl}}\right)^n
\end{equation}
The weak field limit amounts to only needing to keep a finite number of terms in this expansion.

To summarize: there are essentially two expansions: one in powers of $h$ and one in powers of derivatives (that is, powers of curvatures). The Einstein Hilbert action is what you get by working to leading order in the derivative/curvature expansion. Weak gravity is what you get by then on top of that working to leading order in the $h$ expansion.